# My date function in PHP doesn't display the correct time

Tags: php

Here's my PHP code:

```
echo date('M j y g:i:A');
```

This doesn't display correct time. why?

Comment: Check the server's time zone.

Comment: i mean it displays correct date. but incorrect time.

Comment: @rocket: you again?haha. how to check server's time?

Comment: **What time does it display?** Geez. What is the current time, and what time do you get?

Comment: @pekka: sorry, it displays march 8 2011, 7:49pm. but right now here in phil its 3:50am already.

Comment: @New Nope, on the Philippines, it is 3.50am.  @user then it's a time zone issue, correcting the offset as shown below should fix it. Note that the offset may change should you ever decide to move to a different server

Comment: @pekka: yes its philippines, so how to fix it?

@ new guy: no i really mean 3:50am.

Comment: @pekka: can you tell me why this is happening? which part of the world does date() based its time?

Comment: @user 7:50pm is your time minus 8 hours, so it's indeed [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC).

Comment: It is based off of GMT. For the Phillippines you would use (GMT+8).

Comment: i edited my code, but its still incorrect time. the time it displays now is 12:56 am

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your post to included the edited code.

Comment: follow up question. how to insert date and time to a database with datetime datatype, so i can query it and display the inserted date and time.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert this at the very top of your code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
```

Comment: follow up question. how to insert date and time to a database with datetime datatype, so i can query it and display the inserted date and time.?

Comment: Just use `NOW()`, like: `INSERT INTO table VALUES ("random value", NOW())`

Comment: i used it, but i came back to same problem with incorrect time. ive inserted the default time zone. but it wont work on queried dates. help?

Comment: by the way heres how i echo my date from database- echo date('M j y g:i:A', strtotime($fetchcom['date']));

Comment: Right after you connected to the database, do this query: `SET time_zone = 'Asia/Manila'` and then try to insert time again.

Comment: yes i tried this one - echo date('M j y g:i:A', $fetchcom['date']); and it displays jan 1 1970 something. i dunno how that happens

Comment: To use `date()` with a DATETIME type result, you have to do this: `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(column_name) AS column_name FROM table`, which will return a timestamp, instead of a string like 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:ii:ss'

Answer (score 1):

fix the time zone in php.ini or in the code itself

> Add something like this to your
>   php.ini file date.timezone =
>   "Asia/Manila", that will set the
>   default without having you put in the
>   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
>   on every file that uses time functions

Comment: Add something like this to your php.ini file `date.timezone = "Asia/Manila"`, that will set the default without having you put in the `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');` on every file that uses time functions.

Comment: @New Guy im adding that to the answer

Comment: where to locate php.ini file?

Comment: usually if in UNIX/LAMP than in the etc folder

Comment: so look for the php.ini in the PHP folder

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely echoing the time on the server, which is often GMT.  If you're time zone is GMT+5, you may need to add 5 hours to the timestamp.

For 5 hours...

```
$offset = 5 * 60 * 60;
echo date('M j y g:i:A', time() + $offset);
```